# ListView com primeira coluna ultrapassando limite

Tags: c#, winforms, aplicação-desktop, material-design

Olá! Fiz um formulário usando a biblioteca [MaterialSkin](https://github.com/IgnaceMaes/MaterialSkin)

Nessa biblioteca há um componente chamado ListView (que seria semelhante ao ListView do WinForms) que a primeira coluna fica bugada. Vejam essa imagem:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O correto seria ficar os três pontinhos assim como na coluna CPF-CNPJ, porém, a primeira coluna fica sobrepondo todas as outras quando tem muitos caracteres. Alguém sabe qual pode ser a solução pra isso?

Edit 1 : De preferência uma forma que não seja simplesmente dar um substring nos caracteres da primeira coluna!!

Edit 2: Estou preenchendo a tabela com o seguinte código:

```
fornecedores = new Fornecedor().retornaItens(tbFiltro.Text,30);
lstFornecedores.Items.Clear();

    foreach (Fornecedor fornecedor in fornecedores)
    {
        var item = new ListViewItem(new string[ {fornecedor.nome,fornecedor.cpfcnpj,fornecedor.tipoPessoa.ToString(),fornecedor.endereco});
            lstFornecedores.Items.Add(item);
    }
```

Comment: Se você adicionar o código ao invés da imagem, fica mais fácil de ajudar você.

Comment: coloquei amigo!

Comment: Já tentou editar a largura da coluna? `lstFornecedores.Column[index da coluna].Width = "tamanho desejado";` não esquece que ele é um inteiro.

Comment: Sim, já está definida a largura de cada uma das colunas, esse problema só ocorre na primeira coluna. Se você observar, a coluna do CPF/CNPJ já faz o que eu quero automaticamente.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui resolver! Como a falha era só na primeira coluna, eu criei uma primeira coluna com width de 0 e preenchi com uma string vazia. Assim ele corta automaticamente :)

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
fornecedores = new Fornecedor().retornaItens(tbFiltro.Text, 30);
lstFornecedores.Items.Clear();

        foreach (Fornecedor fornecedor in fornecedores)
        {               
            var item = new ListViewItem(new string[]
            {"",fornecedor.nome,fornecedor.cpfcnpj,fornecedor.tipoPessoa.ToString(),fornecedor.endereco});
            lstFornecedores.Items.Add(item);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Bem vamos lá, existem 3 tipos de Auto dimensionamento de coluna:
`ColumnHeaderAutoResizeStyle.None`,
`ColumnHeaderAutoResizeStyle.HeaderSize` e o
`ColumnHeaderAutoResizeStyle.ColumnContent` .

para acertar a coluna[0] da lista basta só alterar a propriedade `SuaLista.Columns[0].AutoResize(ColumnHeaderAutoResizeStyle.None);`

e se cas queira aumentar o largura da coluna, basta alterar a propriedade `SuaLista.Columns[1].Width = 150;` ou maior, por padrão o valor é 60 de width.

Segue exemplo abaixo:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Já tentei também e não funcionou, creio que seja um bug da biblioteca material skin.